# Custom aggregation on two columns naming fruit

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I want to aggregate two columns of a data frame by name, in the following somewhat special way:

- drop the `parts` column in the result by specially aggregating the two columns `fruits` and `parts`
- while the `parts` values for Apple, Banana and Strawberry doesn't matter and everything gets summarized, the `parts` values of Grape and Kiwi should become the new `fruits` name
- result (at bottom) should have 8 aggregated rows instead of 20

This may sound dead simple on the first sight, but after hours of trial and error I didn't find any useful solution. Here's the example:

```
theDF <- data.frame(dates = as.Date(c(today()+20)),
    fruits = c("Apple","Apple","Apple","Apple","Banana","Banana","Banana","Banana",
      "Strawberry","Strawberry","Strawberry","Strawberry","Grape", "Grape",
      "Grape","Grape", "Kiwi","Kiwi","Kiwi","Kiwi"),
    parts = c("Big Green Apple","Apple2","Blue Apple","XYZ Apple4",
      "Yellow Banana1","Small Banana","Banana3","Banana4",
      "Red Small Strawberry","Red StrawberryY","Big Strawberry",
       "StrawberryZ","Green Grape", "Blue Grape", "Blue Grape",
       "Blue Grape","Big Kiwi","Small Kiwi","Big Kiwi","Middle Kiwi"),
    stock = as.vector(sample(1:20)) )
```

The current data frame:

[image]

The desired output:

[image]

Comment: I think you need `require(lubridate)` for the `today()` function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  If there are patterns like the end character is capital letter or a number in 'parts' column to be removed, we can use `sub` to do that and use as a grouping variable along with 'dates' and get the `sum` of the 'stock'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(theDF)[,.(stock = sum(stock)) , .(dates, fruits = sub("([0-9]|[A-Z])$", "", parts))]
#        dates      fruits stock
#1: 2016-06-19       Apple    46
#2: 2016-06-19      Banana    35
#3: 2016-06-19  Strawberry    38
#4: 2016-06-19 Green Grape    12
#5: 2016-06-19  Blue Grape    21
#6: 2016-06-19    Big Kiwi    37
#7: 2016-06-19  Small Kiwi    14 
#8: 2016-06-19 Middle Kiwi     7
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, we can similarly implement the same methodology.

```
library(dplyr)
theDF %>%
    group_by(dates, fruits = sub('([0-9]|[A-Z])$', '', parts)) %>% 
    summarise(stock = sum(stock))
```

#### Update

If there are no patterns and only based on manually identifying the elements in 'fruits', create a `vector` of elements, use `%chin%` to get the logical index in 'i', assign (`:=`) the values in 'parts' corresponding to the 'i' to 'fruits', then do the group by 'dates', 'fruits' and get the `sum` of 'stock'.

```
setDT(theDF)[as.character(fruits) %chin% c("Grape", "Kiwi"),
          fruits := parts][, .(stock = sum(stock)), .(dates, fruits)]
```

#### data

```
theDF <- structure(list(dates = structure(c(16971, 16971, 16971, 16971, 
16971, 16971, 16971, 16971, 16971, 16971, 16971, 16971, 16971, 
16971, 16971, 16971, 16971, 16971, 16971, 16971), class = "Date"), 
    fruits = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Apple", 
    "Banana", "Grape", "Kiwi", "Strawberry"), class = "factor"), 
    parts = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 16L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 13L, 9L, 12L), .Label = c("Apple1", 
    "Apple2", "Apple3", "Apple4", "Banana1", "Banana2", "Banana3", 
    "Banana4", "Big Kiwi", "Blue Grape", "Green Grape", "Middle Kiwi", 
    "Small Kiwi", "StrawberryX", "StrawberryY", "StrawberryZ"
    ), class = "factor"), stock = c(8, 19, 15, 4, 6, 18, 1, 10, 
    9, 16, 11, 2, 12, 13, 5, 3, 17, 14, 20, 7)), .Names = c("dates", 
"fruits", "parts", "stock"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for your great and fast replay @akrun. But my exapmle was misleading I think. In my real datafarem there are no numbers or big letters. Everthying is mixed. Eg. there are also "Big Strawberry". So I need a solution which works by manually *selecting* the **parts** names.

Comment: @MHN You mentioned manually selecting `parts` names.  Is there any other patterns where we could rely on?  For example, how do you select the entry in `parts` or `fruits` column?

Comment: I have edited the original post. Sorry for the inconvenience. In fact there isn't any logical pattern. I think this is a good decription for my issue - aggreagting columns without any pattern.

Comment: Absolutely marvelous! This is exactly what I wanted. Really great! Thanks alot.

Comment: Hi, unfortunatly I needed to make a new Edit above, since there occured a new problem. Maybe you have an idea to solve this? Thanks :)

Comment: I deleted the new question, because the newly occured problem can't be done programmatically.

Comment: Does it mean it is possible? Reopened the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569328/aggregating-two-data-frame-columns-without-any-existing-pattern-logic

Comment: @MHN Let me check that question

Comment: @MHN: if you have unstructured columns, you can still use regex to grep for `'.*(Apple|Banana|Strawberry|Grape|Kiwi)'`. And if you just take the rightmost word from `parts` (without the trailing number), don't you get a list of all possible fruits?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is just to create an appropriate grouping variable in a first step, and then to use whatever method you prefer to summarize by group. Here, I use `dplyr`, you could use others (`data.table`, etc).

```
library(dplyr)
theDF <- data.frame(fruits, parts, stock, stringsAsFactors = F)
theDF$fruits <- with(theDF, ifelse(fruits=="Kiwi" | fruits=="Grape", parts, fruits))

theDF %>% group_by(fruits) %>% summarise(stock = sum(stock))

Source: local data frame [8 x 2]

       fruits stock
        (chr) (int)
1       Apple    34
2      Banana    35
3    Big Kiwi    26
4  Blue Grape    32
5 Green Grape     7
6 Middle Kiwi    12
7  Small Kiwi    19
8  Strawberry    45
```

I did not find the function `today()`, so I skipped the date-column. You can add it back by inserting `date` into the grouping, as in `group_by(fruits, date)` to keep it in the desired output.