# Aggregating two data frame columns without any existing pattern logic

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to aggregate the values of a data frame by quasi *merging* two columns.

On one hand some row values (changing the names) needs to be changed, on the other hand a manual aggregation without any pattern or logic needs to be made. Since this may sound complex or unintelligibly, please check the example code and images.

The data set looks like this:

```
set.seed(1253)
dates <- as.Date(c(Sys.Date()+10))
fruits <- c("Apple","Apple","Apple","Apple","Banana","Banana","Banana","Banana",
  "Strawberry","Strawberry","Strawberry","Strawberry","Grape", "Grape",
  "Grape","Grape", "Kiwi","Kiwi","Kiwi","Kiwi")
parts <- c("Big Green Apple","Default","Blue Apple","XYZ Apple4",
  "Yellow Banana1","Small Banana","Banana3","Banana4",
  "Red Small Strawberry","Red StrawberryY","Big Strawberry", "StrawberryZ",
  "Green Grape", "Green Grape", "Blue Grape", "Blue Grape", 
  "Big Kiwi","Small Kiwi", "Kiwi","Default")
stock <- as.vector(sample(1:20))

theDF <- data.frame(dates, fruits, parts, stock)

theDF
```

[image]

The intermediate step to correct aggregation:

[image]

The final data frame should look like this:

[image]

Hopefully, there is a solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use `set.seed` to make this reproducible as `sample` is used

Comment: @Frank - give me a few mins to edit the whole post, since I made another mistake with the Green and Blue Grape.

Comment: @akrun Hopefully it's now possible to find a solution

Comment: @Hack-R yes, just added the right one

Comment: Somebody already added the solution.  So, hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set.seed(1253)
dates <- as.Date(c(Sys.Date()+10))
fruits <- c("Apple","Apple","Apple","Apple","Banana","Banana","Banana","Banana",
            "Strawberry","Strawberry","Strawberry","Strawberry","Grape", "Grape",
            "Grape","Grape", "Kiwi","Kiwi","Kiwi","Kiwi")
parts <- c("Big Green Apple","Default","Blue Apple","XYZ Apple4",
           "Yellow Banana1","Small Banana","Banana3","Banana4",
           "Red Small Strawberry","Red StrawberryY","Big Strawberry", "StrawberryZ",
           "Green Grape", "Green Grape", "Blue Grape", "Blue Grape", 
           "Big Kiwi","Small Kiwi", "Kiwi","Default")
stock <- as.vector(sample(1:20))

theDF <- data.frame(dates, fruits, parts, stock)

theDF
```

There are several ways to do this, if you have a lot more values of "parts" I'd recommend using some custom regex to help out. With only a manageable number like this it's easier to do it as follows.

```
theDF$fruits <- as.character(theDF$fruits)

theDF$fruits[theDF$fruits == "Grape" & theDF$parts == "Blue Grape"]  <- "Small Grape"
theDF$fruits[theDF$fruits == "Grape" & theDF$parts == "Green Grape"] <- "Big Grape"

df <- aggregate(theDF$stock, by = list(theDF$dates, theDF$fruits), FUN = sum)
colnames(df) <- c("dates", "fruits", "stock")

df
       dates      fruits stock
1 2016-06-11       Apple    40
2 2016-06-11      Banana    37
3 2016-06-11   Big Grape    15
4 2016-06-11        Kiwi    33
5 2016-06-11 Small Grape    21
6 2016-06-11  Strawberry    64
>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this finally fixed the problem with the dataset! :)

Comment: @MHN Happy to help